# WebDriverException: Target URL No Value is not well-formed. Command duration or timeout: 323 milliseconds

Tags: java, selenium

Selenium Issue:

While i am going to navigate url in firefox its getting navigated but after website opened if i am going to click on any link its showing:

> "The address is not valid" in firefox page

In eclipse error is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Target URL No Value is not well-formed. Command duration or timeout:
>   323 milliseconds

Comment: Does manually navigate correctly???

Comment: To overcome from this issue you need to setPreference as `firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur ... Yea manually its navigating correctly . while writing this code than its saying make a local variable , what to do

Comment: Ok you need to create `FirefoxProfile`..to set above preference

Comment: How to create FirefoxProfile  @ SaurabhGaur

Comment: `final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);` like this

Comment: then you can use `driver` to navigate

Comment: issue is not handle yet ..same things is showing after including this code also

Comment: What is the version of your `selenium`???

Comment: Can you put the exact url you have used in `driver.get()`

Comment: Selenium version 2.53.1 & firefox version 33.1 , OS windows10 #SaurabhGaur & url what i have used is :                                                     "   http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/   " 
@Madhan

Comment: Have you used it as `driver.get("http://www.amarchitrakatha.com")` or `driver.get("amarchitrakatha.com");`

Comment: you mean this one `driver.get("http://www.amarchitrakatha.com")`???

Comment: yea first one h t t p : ./ / www.amarchitrakatha.com

Comment: would you upgrade your firefox to 45???

Comment: i have done with firefox 45 but not succeed .

Comment: @Sam Please share your full code which have you tried....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.